# Do Bach Chorales in minor keys ever modulate to the dominant major?

Tags: harmony, modulation, j-s-bach

I am wondering if any of you are able to help me with this question regarding modulation. An example would be E Minor to B Major. Does Bach ever use this?

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen this described in any texts. Normally in the minor one, modulates to III or v. A modulation to V would not be "closely related" nor is it a chromatic median. It's not discussed in some statistical analyses of Bach.
http://www.lukedahn.net/ChoraleIndex.htm

I'd guess that such a modulation would seem like a prolonged dominant. According to Schoenberg's comments, to modulate to E-major from a-minor, one would have to in some sense introduce the notes: F#, C#, G#, and D#. At this point, one has chromaticized more than half the original notes. That may be too abrupt for an immediate goal.

Comment: In A minor, there exists the notes F# and G# already. Now only half !

Comment: Yes exactly it would be a very abrupt and akward modulation. It would probably not sound very musical.

Comment: But in A minor, F# and G# are really part of F and G; all are diatonic to the minor key. (Not really 9 notes but 7 notes with numbers 6 and 7 mutable.)

Answer (score 1):

Having looked through all 371 chorales in the Riemenschneider edition, I didn't find any such modulations. The closest I found were instances like the following, in "Du, o schönes Weltgebäude":

[image]

The main problem in examples like this is that the A chord isn't major until the moment of cadence; the presence of C♮ and F♮ leading into this cadence really means that this is a cadence in A *minor*, just with a Picardy-third effect at the resolution.

(This example also has another problem: this is a clear Dorian melody that already has a B♮, thereby "weakening" the original D minor. But not all examples have this.)

In addition to the fact that J. S. Bach often stuck to closely related keys in his modulation, I think there might be another very good reason he never used a i to V modulation. In order to convincingly move to the major dominant, Bach needed to use the major scale-degree three of the dominant key. But unfortunately, this is the leading tone of the original tonic. As such, any cadence to the dominant major risks being confused with a half cadence in the original key. Perhaps to avoid this issue, Bach just ignored this kind of modulation entirely.